# Duvida sobre o iis 6 com asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em asp.net mvc 5 no framework 4.5. Vi um comentário por aqui que o iis 6 não suporta o framework 4.5, apenas o 4.0, isso procede ?
Se sim, como faço para fazer a conversão da aplicação do 4.5 para o 4.0 ?

Comment: Não seria melhor atualizar o IIS? Ficar com versões antigas é um grande problema.

Comment: @bigown é meio complicado aqui na empresa cara, os caras não querem essa opção.

Comment: É, eu sei como é, o pessoal prefere o caminho mais difícil, o caminho que vai dar mais problema, mais trabalho, mais custo. Um dia o mercado vai ter melhores profissionais.

Comment: Verdade @bigown .. rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o .NET 4.5 não pode ser instalado no windows server 2003.

mas como voce falou ali, tem como mudar sim a versão do seu projeto.

Se você usa o visual studio, faça o seguinte:
Abra o solution explorer ( `ctrl` + `alt` + `L`)
depois click com o botão direito em cima do nome do projeto e vai em `properties`
Depois que  abrir as propriedade do projeto, vá na aba `Application`  e mude o `Target Framework` para `.NET Framework 4`. Salve suas alterações e de um rebuild na solution.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu fiz isso e o iis6 ainda não abre meu projeto cara .. :S

Comment: quando voce tentar rodar o seu projeto, o que voce tem como retorno? alguma msg de erro ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Como estava vendo ali sua aplicação é MVC 5, e pra usar o MVC5 o servidor deve suportar  .NET 4.5 ou superior.
Duas soluções é você tentar trocar de servidor, ou desenvolver sua APP em MVC 4

Comment: É, imaginei que fosse isso. Sabe se dá pra voltar a versão do mvc pro 4?

Comment: Um downgrade não sei se é possivel. ja vi um colega criando um novo projeto em mvc4 e aproveitando os controles as views e os modelos... ele conseguiu aproveitar quase tudo.

Comment: Comecei a fazer isso também, vamos ver se funciona. Valeu @Rafael Cabral